# How to restrict future date using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using date picker in my application which should not allow user to select future date.

I could not find any function in jquery . Please give some suggestions.

I am using html 5 date input type.

```
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

Comment: What kind of datepicker? jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: For [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max): `Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<input id="yourOwnId" type="date" name="bday">
```

Then with jquery and UI datepicker plugin for example if your future date is today:

```
$("#yourOwnId").datepicker({
       dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
       maxDate : '12/10/2012
});
```

Or simply according to [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster):

```
maxDate: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the jQuery UI Datepicker what you are looking for is the [`maxDate` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate). By setting it to `0` you can disallow any dates in the future.

Comment: Why downvote this? It does the job and unlike @Franky's answer it does not require custom code to get the current date.

Comment: Updating your answer to mention that possibility would probably be better

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is extremely vague have a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate.